# Git say everything up to date after successfully commit

Tags: git, git-push

I made changes I commited them:

```
git commit -am "Setup new intention form"
[(null) 9a89b62] Setup new intention form
 3 files changed, 34 insertions(+), 15 deletions(-)
 rewrite intentions/templates/index.html (80%)
```

then I try to push but I am getting always:

> Everything up-to-date

Could somebody give me any advice?

My last commits aren't in git log, so where I can find those commits? :/

git branch gives me:

```
  (null)
* master
```

I tried:

git push
git push origin master
git push HEAD:master

Nothing works

Comment: Maybe your server settings are incorrect... hard to say with the information you gave. What did you check? Is the server remote or local? How did you set it up?

Comment: I edited my answer. Server is bitbucket, earlier everything works ok, I don't think that this is server issue

Comment: from the output of the `git commit` it looks like your commits are going to this `(null)` branch that shows up when you list the branches. How many commits are missing? You probably just need to rebase those commits on top of master.

Comment: 2 commits are missing, how can I rebase them?

Answer (score 2):

What command are you using to push? A `git push` will only push the branches that are following remote branches.

Try running `git push <remote-name> <remote-branch>`. If that push is successful then set your tracking branch with `git branch <local-branch> --set-upstream <remote-name/remote-branch>`.

In the future you can use the `--track` option of `git branch` to set up remote tracking when creating the local branch.